# When are aliases needed in a multi-table conditional insert?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

An example from my Oracle SQL Certified Expert Exam study guide has me puzzled.

The SQL statement:

```
INSERT
  WHEN (BOSS_SALARY-EMPLOYEE_SALARY < 10000) THEN
    INTO SALARY_CHART (EMP_TITLE, SUPERIOR, EMP_INCOME, SUP_INCOME)
    VALUES (EMPLOYEE, BOSS, EMPLOYEE_SALARY, BOSS_SALARY)
SELECT A.POSITION EMPLOYEE
  , B.POSITION BOSS
  , A.MAX_SALARY EMPLOYEE_SALARY
  , B.MAX_SALARY BOSS_SALARY
FROM POSITIONS A
  JOIN POSITIONS B ON A.REPORTS_TO_POSITION_ID = B.POSITION_ID
```

The explanation from the book:

> Note that this version has done more
>   than is required, and applies column
>   aliases to each column in the
>   subquery, then references those column
>   aliases from the WHEN and VALUES
>   clauses.  We only needed column
>   aliases on A.POSITION and B.POSITION
>   in lines 5 and 6, so we can reference the column aliases in line 4.

My source of confusion:

Don't we also **need** the aliases on the two MAX_SALARY columns selected in lines 7 and 8, in order to distinguish them in line 4?  The explanation seems to suggest the EMPLOYEE_SALARY and BOSS_SALARY aliases are extraneous...

Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing they meant they only need it on two columns (eg A.POSITION and A.MAX_SALARY) to disambiguate for the parser.  For example, this would work:

```
INSERT
  WHEN (MAX_SALARY-EMPLOYEE_SALARY < 10000) THEN
    INTO SALARY_CHART (EMP_TITLE, SUPERIOR, EMP_INCOME, SUP_INCOME)
    VALUES (EMPLOYEE, POSITION, EMPLOYEE_SALARY, MAX_SALARY)
SELECT A.POSITION EMPLOYEE
  , B.POSITION 
  , A.MAX_SALARY EMPLOYEE_SALARY
  , B.MAX_SALARY 
FROM POSITIONS A
  JOIN POSITIONS B ON A.REPORTS_TO_POSITION_ID = B.POSITION_ID
```

Comment: That makes sense, and is what I would expect.  So you're saying its just a major typo?

Comment: Yes that is what I think, nothing else makes sense to me.